# Why building a new scorer outputs an empty string for deepspeech 0.9.3

Tags: python, node.js, nlp, mozilla-deepspeech

I am trying to create a limited corpus and train a language model to use for a deepspeech scorer.

I have followed the information provided in [the docs here](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/r0.9/Scorer.html)

I read a helpful guide posted for an older version of deepspeech for generating a language model [here](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/tune-moziiladeepspeech-to-recognize-specific-sentences/41350/22)

And I have read [the playbook here](https://mozilla.github.io/deepspeech-playbook/),

It seems that this has been encountered before, but [no answer was given there](https://github.com/coqui-ai/STT/discussions/1472)

I have set up the docker environment for training and followed the docs to the letter.

I can train a model, and then convert this to a .scorer file, so the whole process is working.

The steps I take from inside the docker container are:

- create a vocab.txt file with my input sentences and store it in the deepspeech-data-input folder.
- run this script to build the model in the output`python3 generate_lm.py --input_txt ../../deepspeech-data/input/vocab.txt --output_dir ../../deepspeech-data/output --top_k 100 --kenlm_bins /DeepSpeech/native_client/kenlm/build/bin/ --arpa_order 5 --max_arpa_memory "85%" --arpa_prune "0|0|0|0" --binary_a_bits 255 --binary_q_bits 8 --binary_type trie --discount_fallback`
- run this script to generate the scorer: `./generate_scorer_package --alphabet ../../deepspeech-data/input/alphabet.txt --lm ../../deepspeech-data/output/lm.binary --vocab ../../deepspeech-data/output/vocab-100.txt --package ../../deepspeech-data/output/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer --default_alpha 0.9 --default_beta 0.9 --force_bytes_output_mode 1`
- replace the default scorer with my one.
- Run deepspeech

Everything seems to work as it should, no errors or anything, but when doing this deepspeech just detects an empty string. If I use the default scorer I have it working fine, but I need to restrict the vocabulary so that I can just detect a few commands.

I have tried adjusting some of the flags, but I always get the same result.

I am using the `--discount_fallback` flag as suggested as it is a small corpus

So my question is this. Why would a deepspeech language model/scrorer output an empty string and how can I fix it?

I am running this inside the NodeJS example on github but testing against any of them would work to reproduce. [github examples](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech-examples)

Comment: Deepspeech is long abandoned, hard to debug problems there.  So is https://github.com/coqui-ai/STT, but less so. I would try that, with the caveat that last time I tried to create a LM, I had to copy `libkenlm.so` to /usr/lib. Also, `force_bytes_output_mode` is for scripts like Chinese, right?

Comment: yeah I've come to understand this about deepspeech, whisper seems to be the new focus, but it doesn't do real time streaming on all platforms yet. I'm keeping an eye on [this](https://github.com/ufal/whisper_streaming) repo though. Thank you for your suggestion I will give it a go.

Comment: Thank you, removing --force_bytes_output_mode 1 solved the problem. Not sure why I added that.